# Tikzpictures side by side

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, tikz-pic

I have used the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]  
\begin{tikzpicture}   
      \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {$x$};  
      \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y$};  
      \draw (0,0.5) -- (4,2);  
      \draw [dashed] (0,1.5) -- (4,4);  
\end{tikzpicture}  
\caption{No Interaction} \label{fig:M1}  

\begin{tikzpicture}  
      \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {$x$};  
      \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y$};  
      \draw (0,0.5) -- (4,2.5);  
      \draw [dashed] (0,1.5) -- (4,3.5);  
\end{tikzpicture}. 
\caption{Interaction} \label{fig:M2}  
\end{figure}
```

to insert two figures, however it places them one on top of the other and I would like them next to each other but labelled independently, is this possible?

Comment: Well, if you want to have two `TikZ` pictures side by side you should not use two captions and no empty lines in between the `tikzpicture` environments. Either use something like `subcaption` package or just one caption for both images.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Two captions force necessarily a line break, so the pictures are above each other, not side by side

Comment: I have removed the captions and they are still above each other

Comment: Because you most likely still have an empty line between

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A `tikzpicture` acts basically like a letter, so if you want to place two letters side by side you should not use any command that inserts vertical space or leave an empty line. In the first example I removed the first caption and combined it with the second one, removing also the empty line in between.

The second solution shows a possible way with `subfigure` from `subcaption` package: Put each `tikzpicture` into a `subfigure` environment and provide a `\caption` for each.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]  
\centering 

\begin{tikzpicture}   
      \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {$x$};  
      \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y$};  
      \draw (0,0.5) -- (4,2);  
      \draw [dashed] (0,1.5) -- (4,4);  
\end{tikzpicture}% NO EMPTY LINE HERE!!!! 
\begin{tikzpicture}  
      \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {$x$};  
      \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y$};  
      \draw (0,0.5) -- (4,2.5);  
      \draw [dashed] (0,1.5) -- (4,3.5);  
\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{Left: No Interaction. Right: Interaction} \label{fig:M}  
\end{figure}  

\begin{figure}[h]  
\centering 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}   
      \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {$x$};  
      \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y$};  
      \draw (0,0.5) -- (4,2);  
      \draw [dashed] (0,1.5) -- (4,4);  
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{No interaction} \label{fig:M1}  
  \end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}  
      \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {$x$};  
      \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y$};  
      \draw (0,0.5) -- (4,2.5);  
      \draw [dashed] (0,1.5) -- (4,3.5);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Interaction} \label{fig:M2}  
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Interaction figures}
\end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

[image]